# Vue binding value to input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a loop of inputs

```
<li v-for="role in ...">
    {{-some html-}}
</li>
```

and have input inside

```
<input type="text" :data-some="role.name" :value="role.name" name="name" ....>
```

And I can bind it to any attribute (for example to data-some) but I cant bind it to value attribute. Why and how I can solve this?

I can`t do this by

```
value="{{role.name}}"
```

since it deprecated

And I dnt want to create another data and use v-model, coz I only need to output value

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see role.name has been bound to custom attr "data-some" and value - dont exists at all.

Comment: Can't you just use `<input type="text" v-model="role.name" name="name" ....>` ?

Comment: No, this not working also

Answer (score 0):

I figure out with this.
Issue - that part was cloned by me into another location via

```
var divWithReactiveInput = document.querySelector('.someclass')
document.querySelector('.someclass').innerHtml = divWithReactiveInput.innerHtml
```

And I expected same reactive behaviour as on original elem.

Ofc, this wont work.